# ClassNotFoundException when applying Japanese filedType

Tags: java, solr

I downloaded Solr version 4.7.0, and then add a filter for Japanese file type like this (using example directory in package):

```
<fieldType name="text_ja_start_with" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.JapaneseTokenizerFactory" mode="search" userDictionary="lang/userdict_ja.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.JapanesePartOfSpeechStopFilterFactory" tags="lang/stoptags_ja.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_ja.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.JapaneseKatakanaStemFilterFactory" minimumLength="4"/>
    <filter class="solr.JapaneseReadingFormFilterFactory" useRomaji="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.ICUTransformFilterFactory" id="Katakana-Hiragana"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.JapaneseTokenizerFactory" mode="search" userDictionary="lang/userdict_ja.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.JapanesePartOfSpeechStopFilterFactory" tags="lang/stoptags_ja.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_ja.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.JapaneseKatakanaStemFilterFactory" minimumLength="4"/>
    <filter class="solr.JapaneseReadingFormFilterFactory" useRomaji="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.ICUTransformFilterFactory" id="Katakana-Hiragana"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The server cannot start because of this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.MultiTermAwareComponent

I've done some searching but it's said that MultiTermAwareComponent is an abstract component of Solr ( http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/MultiTermAwareComponent.html).
So I don't know how to fix this.

Update:

I've found the cause make this error, when I copy 2 libs file (**$root/contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs/lucene-analyzers-icu-4.7.0.jar** and **$root/contrib/analysis-extras/lib/icu4j-52.1.jar**) for **ICUTransformFilterFactory** filter to $root/example/lib/ext, It throw the error above.When not add 2 file to libs directory, the error not happen but cannot use **ICUTransformFilterFactory** filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the problem.

The lib file for filter `ICUTransformFilterFactory` need to be include in `solrconfig.xml`, using  tag, not copy to `lib` folder of `example` directory.

Now it's working.

Thank you all for your help

Comment: The line to add to `solrconfig.xml` is `<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs/" regex="lucene-analyzers-icu-\d.*\.jar" />`.

Answer (score 0):

`MultiTermAwareComponent` is an `interface` and needs to be implemented.

In your filters, apparently you have filtered its implementations out. [CJKWidthFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/cjk/CJKWidthFilterFactory.html) and [LowerCaseFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/LowerCaseFilterFactory.html) are implementing the `interface`. Use this knowledge to fix your filters.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, and I've updated the question about the cause of error, I don't think it's because of MultiTermAwareComponent not implemented.

Comment: Well, anyway, you had a problem of an interface being used without being implemented. This was reflected in my answer, where I have told you about the two classes I've found in your code which implement the interface. Whether you are using other implementations or not filtering out the existent ones, the issue should be solved. Your new issue is also related to either an implementation of an interface missing or a dependency missing. Read the docs attentively, it can help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out, mis-configuration, lib file must be include in solrconfig.xml insteads of copying to lib folder of solr instance.